# TLS-like encryption over Bluetooth on iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, encryption, bluetooth, tls1.2

So, this might be a very special case, but I hope someone can help me out here.

I need to talk to a peripheral via Bluetooth. A device for which we also control the firmware. Now the issue is: we need to make sure noone can eavesdrop as the information to be sent will be confidential. That means we need an encrypted communication.

From what I see is that Bluetooth LE 4.2 supports encryption, BUT we have to be able to support older iPhones than the 6s. That means: no BLE 4.2 and no built in encryption.

In other words: we need to build the encryption ourselves. The peripheral developers and me agreed on using the TLS handshake to communicate the key exchange to reduce the amount of things we could break.

I've spent the last few days searching for solutions and how to tackle this. However this seems to be a very specific case that not a lot of people have tackled. All libraries that I could find rely on sockets. And all I could find about sockets for iOS was IP networking, not Bluetooth.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of Bluetooth communication? Or some other suggestions? Maybe some obvious solution that I'm overlooking?

Thanks :)

Comment: Encrypted GATT attributes are supported on the iphone4s and above and iPad mini and up (ie any device with BLE). BLE 4.2 has better encryption and support for encrypting the whole connection but the main thing it gives you is protection against MITM attacks during pairing. Is this a big risk for you?

Comment: How much RAM / code space do you have in the peripheral and how fast is your cpu?

Comment: Pre-v4.2 BLE does support AES-CCM encryption but with limited protection against eavesdropping. i.e if the eavesdropper was present during the pairing process between the iPhone and peripheral, it could get the shared keys and listen in during future encrypted communication. If the eavesdropper was not present during the pairing process, it would not be able to decipher the encrypted data.

Comment: What are your goals? Is it only to secure your firmware? If so, store an encryption key securely inside the peripheral as well as an RSA public key used for signature verification. Then just send the firmware encrypted and signed.

Comment: @Paulw11 as far as I can see (please correct me if I'm wrong) you'd need to enter a code on the Smartphone that is displayed on the Bluetooth peripheral so you can bond. But: our peripheral does not have a display. No bonding possible.

Comment: @Emil we have as much hardware as current smartphones have. Whatever the end consumer uses, whether that is an iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6s or some iPad..

The goal is not to protect the firmware. The goal is to protect the secrets being exchanged with the peripheral. The important part is: we can't use symmetric encryption for various reasons. So no predefined keys for the peripheral.

Comment: @user3732210 that is actually a real threat for our application. Many people may be able to listen in during the pairing process.

Comment: If you can't bond securely then even BLE 4.2 won't help you. https://pomcor.com/2015/06/03/has-bluetooth-become-secure/

Comment: You can always run a custom encryption / authentication scheme on top of BLE, especially if BLE 4.x pairing is not good enough.

Comment: How would you like to authenticate both ends and protect from MITM attacks? Do you have certificates or would you rather like to use passkey comparison? Maybe only one side needs to be authenticated (like normally on HTTPS)?

Comment: @Emil: We'd like to do it as closely to HTTPS (that is TLS) as possible. And we are aiming for certificates, yes.

Comment: @Paulw11: We don't need to create a bond. We need to exchange secret information with the peripheral without others listening in (public key encryption with key exchange like TLS does) and then we aim to use certificates on one end for authentication. The rationale is: if TLS is safe, then we can exchange keys with "TLS over Bluetooth" safely aswell.

The question is: how to do this on iOS?

Comment: You can hard code a private key in your Bluetooth device. Your app can then use the corresponding public key to encrypt a session key and send that to the device. Then your app and the device can exchange messages encrypted with that session key using AES or similar.

Comment: @Paulw11 no we can't, really. There can be many many peripherals and we can't use the same key for every peripheral. Also for practical reasons we can't have the peripheral have unique key pairs as we can't ship the app containing all public keys to all peripherals. Internet connection may not be given always so we can't poll a server neither.

So really, the most straight forward solution for this would be to use TLS. :)

Comment: What I described is effectively the core of TLS. With TLS (at least) one end has a fixed public/private key pair. This is required for secure exchange of the session key. Since you don't trust the connection to be safe against eavesdropping you can't share the session key across the link without encrypting it. Encrypting it requires a pre-shared asymmetric key. It doesn't matter if all devices use the same public/private key pair as long as it is reasonably difficult for an attacker to extract the private key from the embedded firmware. If this is too much of a risk then use a cable not BT

Answer (score 6):

The whole foundation in TLS builds upon trust, i.e. Certificates, Certificate authorities and certification chains, and making sure all data sent and received are authenticated. You could say the whole security relies on the authentication part. The encryption itself is quite straight-forward. One question you should answer is:

Should it be possible to connect to peripherals that mimic your protocol, i.e. peripherals NOT manufactured by you? If not, with your premises you must have some (unique) secret in each peripheral, for example a private key. The corresponding public key can be signed by your own CA. The public key of the CA can be bundled in your smartphone app (so you need only one key in your app, not one for all peripherals). That way you can verify that the peripheral you connect to is made by your company. This public key should also be *the* identifier of the peripheral. If you don't have a private / public key pair inside your peripheral and can't do passkey comparison and don't have any shared symmetric key, as far as I know it's impossible to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

Since each smartphone must also initially be treated unauthenticated, if you need to resume a session later, you need to store some unique ID assigned to each smartphone in the peripheral.

With this in mind, you have basically three different options:

1. Try to modify some present TLS server software like mbedtls to send all packets over BLE rather than sockets. I have a feeling this might be non-trivial because it seems it's based on the concept of blocking sockets.
2. Just read the TLS spec on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246 and implement a minimal TLS server with only the features you need. This is actually not so hard as it may look like first if you only do a minimal implementation and use existing building blocks such as RSA, AES, SHA-2, ECDHE, X.509 certificate parsing code (you can find those here: https://tls.mbed.org/source-code).
3. Extract the important parts in TLS and make a simplified protocol without all negotiation parameters (since they can be hardcoded). For example, you don't need to send and be able to parse all kind of messages (for example ClientHello), handle fragmentation etc. Just send the random values, certificates, signed data, encrypted data directly.

Comment: Outdated, but might be interesting for newcomers. (1) can be done with non-blocking I/O as well. mbedtls (and other SSL implementations) do support that. Do NOT go for (2) or (3) unless you are a security expert and even in that case, it is not recommended. Never roll your own.