# Objective C Secure Transport Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, tls1.2, secure-transport

After several days of research about how to use Secure Transport i found that all the example and projects are working with BSD sockets and Streams.

In Apple documentation there is no statement confirming or denying the possibility of applying TLS over Core Bluetooth.

I have tried in many ways to establish a TLS session between two iOS devices that exchange data via Core Bluetooth. However i always get error **-9806** every time i call the **SSLHandShake()** method.

In almost every example, a BSD Socket should be configured and connected before starting TLS HandShake.
Once the Socket is connected, Secure Transport exchanges automatically the TLS settings between two peers after calling **SSLHandShake()** method.

I suppose that Secure Transport supports BSD Sockets when it comes to establish a TLS HandShake. I did not find any solution to make Secure Transport exchange TLS settings between two peers connected via Core Bluetooth (BLE).

Is it possible to establish a TLS session between two iOS devices that have been connected via Core Bluetooth ? Should i forget about Secure Transport and implement TLS protocol (over Core Bluetooth) by myself without using Secure Transport ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/38662923 ?

Comment: Solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @rokridi how? Can you post an answer?