# iOS - TLS over BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, tls1.2, secure-transport

I m currently working on iOS BLE application. To secure the connection between the smartphone which is in Central mode and the head unit which is in peripheral mode we need to implement TLS protocole over BLE.

To send the certificate which is big data for BLE we will use a segmentation protocole.

We need to use TLS because we can't be hack easily on our system and BLE 4.2 which is more secure than 4.0 is not implement in enough phone.

I have see that secure transport allow to make TLS on iOS (https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/secure_transport) and I have not see that I can't implement it over BLE.

Did someone have already implement TLS with secure transport?

If yes can he explain me how I can use it in my case? Or if I can't use it can he explain me why?

Comment: tls is basically for the web,

Comment: What's your use case? What's your hardware? Could you start reading this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662923/tls-like-encryption-over-bluetooth-on-ios/38703507#38703507

Comment: Hi Emil, I already read this post and thank for it. But before create my own TLS I would see if I can't use iOS framework to do it. That why I try to do it with secure transport. And in the Overview of secure transport you can read "There are no transport layer dependencies in this API" and "You can use it with BSD Sockets and other protocols". So for me normally you can use it with BLE.

Comment: @anté75 did you come to a solution?

Comment: @deed02392 Yes we made work secure transport over BLE

Comment: @anté75 would you consider adding some notes on how you achieved that? I've found loads of posts on this problem and zero on how it's solved